# How can i supress Api error and return a value instead?

Tags: angular, rxjs, ts-mockito

I get a `404` for unused and a 204 for used email from my API. Now i want to transform that to `boolean` (true/false) using `rxjs`/`pipe` and `catchError`.

```
emailAvailable(): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.api.email(email).pipe(
    map((response: HttpResponse<any>) => {
      return false; // used email > false
    }),
    catchError((err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      if (err.status === 404) {
        return of(true); // unused > true
      }
      throw err;
    })
  );
}
```

Now in my unit test i have the case for an unused e-mail defined like this

```
when(mockApi.email('unused@example.com')).thenThrow(
  new HttpErrorResponse({status: 404, statusText: 'E-Mail not in use', error: { message: 'E-Mail not in use'}}));
```

And then it try to write my test like this.

```
it('should validate for unused email', async() => {
    expect(await readFirst(emailService.emailAvailable('unused@example.com'))).toBe(true);
});
```

Now the test fails because an `HttpErrorResponse` is thrown:

```
 ● EmailValidator › should validate form for unused email
    HttpErrorResponse: Http failure response for (unknown url): 404 E-Mail not in use
```

So the `Observable` throws the error i thought i catched with `catchError`.
My test setup is `jest`, i do not want to (nor can i) switch to TestBed.

Comment: What happens if instead of re-throwing the error, you return another observable, like `return EMPTY`?

Comment: @AndreiGătej i try to catch the 404 case, in wich i do not throw an error but when listening with readFirst it still throws an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What helped me is this Post:

[Angular 7 - catching HttpErrorResponse in unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53615585/angular-7-catching-httperrorresponse-in-unit-tests)

the "throw error" path should return the error inside an "of" so it gets testable also.

the mock can end up like this:

```
when(mockApi.email('unused@example.com')).thenReturn(
  throwError(new HttpErrorResponse(
    { status: 404, statusText: 'E-Mail not in use', error: { message: 'E-Mail not in use'} } 
)));
```

And in that Test you can check for your value or that error message